# How do I make an instance to my class in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands  

intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True, reactions=True, members=True, presences=True,guild_messages = True)


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!dc ", intents=intents)

#I've created the below class so that every user can have their own number of saying swear words.

class handling_swearwords :

    def __init__(self,swearwords = 0):
        self.swearwords = swearwords
        
    def __del__(self):
        print("One user has left the server .")


@client.event  
async def on_ready():  
    print("I am ready!")

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):   
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.text_channels, name="welcome")
    await channel.send(f"{member.name},welcome to the server,mate.")
   
    member_instance = member.name
    member_instance = handling_swearwords()  #Creating instance to the class.



async def on_member_remove(member):
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.text_channels, name="Lovely-people")
    await channel.send(f"{member.name},see you later mate :(")
    member_instance2 = member.name
    del member_instance2 #If someone leaves the server,their instance will be deleted(at least this is my thought)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):  

    if message.author == client.user:  
        await client.process_commands(message)

    else:
        with open("Badwords.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            word = f.read()
            badwords = word.split(",")
            msg = message.content
            for x in badwords:
                if x in msg:
                    await message.delete()
                    await message.channel.send("Please do not use that word ever")
                    
                    message.author.name.swearwords += 1 #Whenever user use a swearword(s),their number of swearwords will be increased.  
            await client.process_commands(message) 


#I created the below function to check whether there is a attribute which is called 'swearwords' or not.



client.run(Token)
```

Whenever someone writes swear words into the chatbox I got **'str' object has no attribute 'swearwords'** error.I am not very good at OOP so I couldn't solve this problem.So can someone help me to solve this problem?Thank you

PS:I think I got that error because of **message.author.name.swearwords += 1**code line(or not idk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for a way to keep track of how many swear words each member uses. Although you can create your own class and object to do this, that would be the same as using a Python dictionary but with extra steps.

I recommend using member IDs instead of names because IDs are more reliable. You also don't need to read from a file on every message; you can have the program read it once when the bot starts.

Here's an example of how you could do all of this:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True, reactions=True, members=True, presences=True,guild_messages = True)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!dc ", intents=intents)
swearword_count = dict()  # The keys are member IDs (ints), and each value is the number of swearwords that member used (also ints).


with open("Badwords.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    word = f.read()
    badwords = word.split(",")


@client.event  
async def on_ready():  
    print("I am ready!")


@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):   
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.text_channels, name="welcome")
    await channel.send(f"{member.name},welcome to the server,mate.")
    global swearword_count
    swearword_count[member.id] = 0


async def on_member_remove(member):
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.text_channels, name="Lovely-people")
    await channel.send(f"{member.name},see you later mate :(")
    global swearword_count
    del swearword_count[member.id]


@client.event
async def on_message(message):  
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    
    global swearword_count
    global badwords
    msg = message.content
    for x in badwords:
        if x in msg:
            await message.delete()
            await message.channel.send("Please do not use that word ever")
            swearword_count[message.author.id] += 1 #Whenever user use a swearword(s),their number of swearwords will be increased.  
            return

    await client.process_commands(message)


client.run(Token)
```

p.s. - The reason why `message.author.name.swearwords` gave you the error `'str' object has no attribute 'swearwords'` is because `message.author.name` is of the built-in Python type `str`, which only has [its own limited number of built-in methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) that you cannot add to. The error traceback should confirm the line of code that the error came from.